# How to detect <br> tag which currently is not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add `<br />` to the content within the `< p ="minimize"> < /p>` Currently even if there is `<br />` in the string, in the output all strings are shown in 1 line without any `<br />`.

The code below does not seem to detect `<br />`.

```
jQuery(function(){

    var minimized_elements = $('p.minimize');

    minimized_elements.each(function(){    
        var t = $(this).text();        
        if(t.length < 100) return;

        $(this).html(
            t.slice(0,100)+'<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">More</a>'+
            '<span style="display:none;">'+ t.slice(100,t.length)+' <a href="#" class="less">Less</a></span>'
        );

    }); 

    $('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide().prev().hide();
        $(this).next().show();        
    });

    $('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();    
    });

});
```

really appreciate your valuable input and time

Comment: Add your html too so that we can check

Comment: < p ="minimize"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus. <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.< /p>

Comment: doing so the br tag isnt working all string display together

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:-

`< p ="minimize">` need to be `<p class="minimize"> //remove space and add class`

And then it will work fine:-

Example:-

```js
jQuery(function(){

    var minimized_elements = $('p.minimize');

    minimized_elements.each(function(){    
        var t = $(this).text();        
        if(t.length < 100) return;

        $(this).html(
            t.slice(0,100)+'<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">More</a>'+
            '<span style="display:none;">'+ t.slice(100,t.length)+' <a href="#" class="less">Less</a></span>'
        );

    }); 

    $('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide().prev().hide();
        $(this).next().show();        
    });

    $('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();    
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="minimize"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus. <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p><br>
<p class="minimize"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus. <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p>
```

Comment: somehow it does not seem to take any affect on my localhost i still do not the line break, the space i added here because without space the code was not shoing in stack

Comment: @Roger either create a example link like fiddle. Or post your complete code (HTML+Css+Javascript) so that i can check

Comment: yes just gimme a min ill create a fiddle and get back

Comment: @Roger  glad to help you::):)